# Is every normal matrix nonsingular?

Tags: matrices

Is every normal matrix nonsingular?

I don't think so but I can't think of any counter examples.

Comment: What about the null matrix ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The zero matrix is normal, so there's at least some examples.